# Kotlin/Native cinterop: compilerOpts inside .def file vs compilerOpts inside gradle

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native, cinterop

In documentation of `cinterop` for `Kotlin/Native`, you have to define a `.def` file such as:

```
language = Objective-C
modules = FirebaseCore
compilerOpts = -framework FirebaseCore
linkerOpts = -framework FirebaseCore
```

Now you could also specify a `compilerOpts` within the `cinterop` block such as:

```
compilations["main"].cinterops {
    firebasecore {
        packageName 'cocoapods.FirebaseCore'
        defFile = file("$projectDir/src/iosMain/c_interop/FirebaseCore.def")
        includeDirs ("$projectDir/../iosApp/Pods/FirebaseCore/Firebase/Core/Public")
        compilerOpts ("-F$projectDir/src/iosMain/c_interop/modules/FirebaseCore-${versions.firebaseCoreIos}")
    }
}
```

I only took this example by Kevin Galligan here: [KMPFirestore](https://github.com/touchlab/FirestoreKMP).

I'm really confuse whats the difference between `compilerOpts` inside gradle vs `compilerOpts` inside `.def` file?

I have no strong C background and I'm just trying to learn `Kotlin Multiplatform` (and for now just trying to understand how to interop with c or objectiveC libraries) but I can't properly set them up.

I would really appreciate some help as I don't even fully understand how `.def` file work.

Any reading material related to understanding these things would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the two compilerOpts will be merged when generating the interops. Sadly the linkerOpts does not work this way. But for me to make the interop work correctly and link, I had to specify the frameworks' absolute path for the linkerOpts too in the .def file.

Comment: By merge do you mean when `compilerOpts` in gradle is defined as `compilerOpts -someOptions` and `compilerOpts` in `.def` file is defined as `compilerOpts -anotherOption`, the resulting `compilerOpts` is `-someOption -anotherOption`? Is there a way for me to verify that it works this way? (Im completely new to this :( ) Also if linkerOpts doesn't work the same way how does it work?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I mean. 

For example, .def has compilerOpts = -framework Firebase, and then I add a `compilerOpts += "-F$projectDir/cinterop/fws"`  to my gradle cinterop config, then the compiler will receive it like `-F/User/XYZ/project/cinterop/fws -framework Firebase`. 

If you run the linking task from command line with --info flag, then gradle will show commands run by the cinterop task, which will contain the compilerOpts.

For the linkerOpts part, there is a variable in gradle config which works the same as compilerOpts, but gradle build will warn you that its ignored.

Comment: I see thank you very much. Is there a documentation of what options I could use for linkerOpts nad compilerOpts?  Like what does -framework mean?

Comment: All my knowledge about the topic comes from here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/c_interop.html and tons of github searches. And of course hours of trials and failures... :(